train facial recognision model with less data
I am using dlib for facial detection for getting face images of the user and cnn for recognision model. I want the model to get trained with as much as less image data and im trying to train the recognision model with CNN and im not able to increase accuracy of the model. I have increased the data size and i agumented it still im not attaining the accuracy but sometimes when i increase data size the model training is early stoping. Tell me any suggessions to improve my model recognision process by getting into proper strategy.
this is my CNN model for facial recognision.
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, LearningRateScheduler
import os
import numpy as np
class EarlyStoppingWithMessage(EarlyStopping):
    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        if self.stopped_epoch > 0:
            print(f"Model has early stopped at epoch {self.stopped_epoch + 1}")
# Corrected typos in ImageDataGenerator parameters
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest',
    validation_split=0.2
)
train_dir = 'C:\\Users\\aatma\\Desktop\\facRec\\image_dataset\\'
if not os.path.isdir(train_dir):
    raise ValueError(f"The directory {train_dir} does not exist.")
else:
    print(f"Contents of {train_dir}:")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(train_dir):
        print(root, dirs, len(files))
target_size = (224, 224)
batch_size = 32
# Corrected typos in flow_from_directory parameters
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=target_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',  # corrected from catogorical
    subset='training'
)
print('num_classes: ',len(train_generator.class_indices))
validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=target_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation'  # set as validation data
)
# CNN model
model = Sequential()
# model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
# model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',  input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(len(train_generator.class_indices), activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())
# class EarlyStoppingWithMessage(EarlyStopping):
#     def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
#         if self.stopped_epoch > 0:
#             print(f"Model has early stopped at epoch {self.stopped_epoch + 1}")
def step_decay_schedule(initial_lr=0.001, decay_factor=0.5, step_size=15):
    def schedule(epoch, lr):
        return initial_lr * (decay_factor ** np.floor(epoch / step_size))
    return LearningRateScheduler(schedule)
lr_scheduler = step_decay_schedule(initial_lr=0.001, decay_factor=0.1, step_size=10)
early_stopping_message = EarlyStoppingWithMessage(monitor='val_loss', patience=20, restore_best_weights=True)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(
    train_generator,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    epochs=55,
    callbacks=[lr_scheduler, early_stopping_message]
)
model.save('C:\\Users\\aatma\\Desktop\\facRec\\model_1.h5')


I'm not a Community bot you'd rather edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer
